# Python Regex - How do I fetch a word after a specific word in a string using python regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to fetch "repo-name" which is "sonar-repo" from the above multi-line commit string. Can this be achieved with regex? Output Expected: sonar-repo

Here is the string which I need to read using regex,

```
commit_message=
"""repo-name=sonar-repo;repo-title=Sonar;repo-description=A little demo;repo-requester=Jack
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use regex to look for `repo-name=` and then look for the `;` right after and get what's inbetween. Something like this:

```
(?<=repo-name=).*?(?=;)
```

Tested it [here](https://regex101.com/r/W9bC6Y/1) with regex101

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

commit_message= 'repo-name=sonar-repo;repo-title=Sonar;repo-description=A little demo;repo-requester=Jack'

print(re.search(r'repo-name=(.*?);', commit_message).group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
sonar-repo
```